# Hölder's inequality for Schatten norms

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $S_p = S_p(H)$ be a Schatten space on $H$. It is well-known that Hölder's inequality

$$
\|AB\|_{S_r} \leq \|A\|_{S_p} \|B\|_{S_q} 
$$

holds for all $A \in S_p(H)$ and $B \in S_q(H)$ with $1/p + 1/q = 1/r$.

I want to know the following statement is ture or not.

> Let $H_1$, $H_2$ and $H_3$ be Hilbert spaces, and let $S_p(H, K)$ be a Schatten spaces from a Hilbert space $H$ to another Hilbert space $K$. Then, the inequality
> $$ \|AB\|_{S_r(H_1, H_3)} \leq \|A\|_{S_p(H_2,H_3)} \|B\|_{S_q(H_1, H_2)}$$
> holds for all $A \in S_p(H_2,H_3)$ and $B \in S_q(H_1, H_2)$.